# InterstitialAd listener onAdClicked not working

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

> All other listeners of InterstitialAd are working but only onAdLoaded not working.
>
> i have set toast for all listener but onAdLoaded only not getting called but other all are working correctly.
>
> why only onAdClicked() is not working what's wrong with this method

**codes**

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9547225037870226/6863551510");
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                showInterstitial();
            }


            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdImpression() {
                super.onAdImpression();
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad impression", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "ad clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-formatted the code and fixed broken strings

Comment: Please make sure you paste formatted code and also document the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Corrected the sentence: "I have debugged the code and the cursor ..." to make the meaning more understandable

Comment: @gil.fernandes i have changed code and made it clear .please check it.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onAdClicked` is not intended for use with interstitial ads, and isn't invoked for them. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdClicked()):

> Called when a click is recorded for an ad. At the current time, this method is only used with native ads originating from Google in one of the system-defined formats (App Install or Content).

If you'd like to know when the user has clicked on an interstitial, though, you can use the `onAdLeftApplication` method instead. Clickthroughs will result in focus leaving the application, so it's a reliable way to know.

Comment: and how about NativeAd? Its `onAdClicked` is not called when I click on it. Does it mean that I can't click on an ad when I test the ad's implementation on debug builds?